# How to autopromote user to group?

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to autopromote users to the "superuser" group on login, but it is not working

**LocalSettings.php**

```
// Super user group
$wgAddGroups['superuser'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['superuser']['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['superuser']['edit'] = true;
```

**Login plugin**

```
 $wgAutopromote = array('superuser');
```

Answer (score 1):

You want all logged in users to have "superuser" privileges? Simplest approach would be to add additional user rights to the existing `user` user group, rather than creating a new user group.

```
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['some_user_right'] = true;
```

See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MediaWiki manual on $wgAutopromote](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgAutopromote), $wgAutopromote is an associative array.

You could try one of the following:

```php
$wgAutopromote = array('superuser' => array( APCOND_EDITCOUNT, 0 ));
```

Or

```php
$wgAutopromote = array(
        'superuser' => array( '&',
                array( APCOND_EDITCOUNT, 0 ),
        ),
);
```

I don't have a live copy of MediaWiki with me right now, so I don't know which one is going to work, though I have a hunch that the second will likely work.

Comment: Neither of them seem to work. I checked my user profile and it did not list "superuser" group.

Comment: Hmm, maybe join the #mediawiki IRC channel and ask there? irc://irc.freenode.net/#mediawiki

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying for awhile :(

Comment: The first is not even valid PHP. Did you mean `array('superuser' => array( APCOND_EDITCOUNT, 0 ))`?

Comment: The second definitiely works, it is [used on Wikipedia](http://noc.wikimedia.org/conf/highlight.php?file=CommonSettings.php), though you will probably want to merge into `$wgAutopromote` instead of overwriting the defaults.

Comment: Yes, I've changed my first example.

Answer (score 0):

Auto promote is deceptive and does not work in my experience. I ended up having to add the user to the group in my auth plugin extension. I believe I used the add group method from the User object, I'll have to double-check that.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, by the way, if it worked for you.